# Where should I write mapreduce program

Tags: mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

Where should I write map-reduce programs - in text file or anything else ?

What is the file format to save file containing Map-reduce program?

e.g.

In java, text file, having java code saved as filename.java but what will be that for map-reduce program?

Please answer as I need it badly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java to implement Map-reduce Program. Alternatively, you may use other languages including Perl, Python, Ruby, C++, PHP, and R via Hadoop Streaming.

The Map_reduce program will be simple java file like with naming mapreduce.java

Also regarding Map-Reduce or Elastic Map_reduce you can have help in

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-what-is-emr.html

or

[mapreduce count example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164230/mapreduce-count-example)

or

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2008/jw-09-hadoop.html

Thanks